# Type of SQLServer 2008 time(7) don´t match with c# TimeStamp

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, types, sql-server-2008-r2

I have ModelGeneretor that copy colums of database to properties of a Model in c#.
The problem is that i store data as time(7) and in the generator of model I create the model property as TimeStamp.

Then when c# try to match the data the type dont match and generate an exception. 
I see other solution but I cant do it.

What can i do?

Comment: What is a "TimeStamp"?  There is no such type in .NET: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=timestamp

Comment: All SQL Server's datetime data types are mapped to .net DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

Per Microsoft's documentation, the `TIME` type maps to the `TimeSpan` structure in the .NET Framework.

Please see [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)